# to prevent softkeyboard from moving up of layout

Tags: android, xml

When the Softkeyboard shows,it pushes up the rest of the content from the screen.How to adjust this.

I have tried using adjust pan,adjust resize and all the stuffs but those are of no use.

This is my layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/post_header_background"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sender_name_txtvw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/compose_message"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sender_name_txtvw"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_layout"
    tools:ignore="UselessLeaf" >
```

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_btn" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/radus_et_back"
        tools:ignore="TextFields"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my manifest file I have added

```
 <activity  
           android:name="com.radus.ComposeMessageActivity" 
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"                    
           android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|stateVisible"   />
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the softKeyoard by default comming up is your problem..

then try this

In your **activity's** `onCreate()`

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

the keyboard will come only when when your `EditText` is selected or focussed.

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem :

```
<activity android:name=".your_activity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

Comment: This is used to hide the keyboard always.While I am trying to adjust my view when the keyboard pops up i.e to push the view up as soon as the keyboard pops out